# Using R, how do I perform bonferroni type test to decide which areas have move coronavirus cases than expected after performing Chi-square test

Tags: r, statistics, chi-squared

Using R, I have to perform a test to test if the number of coronavirus cases is evenly distributed in some areas in respect to those areas populations and then if they are not evenly distributed with alpha = 0.05, test which areas are different. Our lecturer gave us hints, that whe should perform Chi-Square goodness of fit test to decide if they are evenly distributed, and then perform bonferroni type test to know which areas are different.

I have already performed chi squared test by first calculating probabilities vector as taking populations and dividing them by sum of all populations:

```
populations <-c(2117619, 1428983, 2901225, 1181533, 1014548, 986506, 2466322)
cases <- c(66304, 54354, 89167, 34580, 31573, 36875, 86068)

probabilities.vect <- populations / sum(populations)

chisq.test(x=cases, probabilities.vect)
```

which returns

> Pearson's Chi-squared test
>
> data:  cases and probabilities.vect X-squared = 42, df = 36, p-value =
> 0.227

I dont know why but the code I included above is raising a warning:

> Warning message: In chisq.test(x = cases, probabilities.vect) :
> Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

Did I make some kind of mistake while performing this test?

I also dont know how to perform bonferroni test

Comment: The Bonferonni _correction_ (rather than _test_) adjusts the critical p-value of your test to protect against multiplicity.  It is _highly_ conservative and there are usually better ways of doing this.  If your critical p-value is a and you have n tests, the Bonferonni correction says you should perform each test with a critical p-value of a/n.  Your calculation of your probabilities looks odd.  I would have expected something like `proabilities.vector <- cases / populations`, but I can't be sure because you haven't given any contxt for your data.

Comment: @Limey populations vector contains real populations of administrative regions in my country and cases vector contains a number of cases in each administrative region. I calculated probabilities this way because from my understanding I have to test if the number of cases in proportional to area population, so probability so the number of cases should be something like n*p, where n is the population of the area, and p is the probability of coronavirus occurring. I basically followed example from this site: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/chi-square-goodness-of-fit-test-in-r